# update-grub fails due to syntax error

Tags: grub2

When I run the command "Sudo update-grub" following is the output:

```
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for kamil: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda1
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: line no: 101
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$ uname- a
No command 'uname-' found, did you mean:
 Command 'uname' from package 'coreutils' (main)
uname-: command not found
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$ uname -a
Linux kamil-MG-63MI-7109 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:34:47 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$
```

The file contents etc/default/grub is this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1024x768-24<<,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

the contents of Grub.d are here http://ubuntuone.com/0EXS51BD2bOE5gFC2FdLnI

I don't know how this happened but this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Please tar `/etc/grub.d/*` and post the link to it in the question

Comment: @Amith [link](http://ubuntuone.com/0EXS51BD2bOE5gFC2FdLnI)

I am recalling that I had used a software "Super Boot Manager" but it didn't do anything as I wanted to remove the older kernels through it.

Comment: Maybe this stuff is useful to some who get here from google: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209152/syntax-error-in-grub-cfg-on-update-grub-grub-2/209153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the contents below from a Kubuntu 11.10 install of mine and pasted it in the etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The output when running update-grub:

```
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for kamil: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda1
done
kamil@kamil-MG-63MI-7109:~$
```

Problem Solved.
:-)